# Run OS X Yosemite inside OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, virtualization

I have a MacBook Pro and I am looking for a way to run another OS X Yosemite inside it.

I tried Virtual Box, and installed OS X, but it doesn't support guest additions for OS X guests. It keeps the display at 1024x768 and the mouse moves very slowly.

What is the best way to run OS X inside another OS X? Note that I have a legal OS X and I am not talking about Hackintosh!

Comment: Just a side note: to enable higher resolutions enter `VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode N` where N can be one of 0,1,2,3,4,5 referring to the 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024, 1440x900, 1920x1200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [Parallels Desktop 10](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/whats-new/) and [VMWare fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/features.html) support virtualising Yosemite. Both are better than Virtual Box.

In Parallels you can create a virtual machine with Yosemite immediately by using the recovery partition.

Comment: Parallels Desktop works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have VMware Fusion running on 10.10 Yosemite. It has no problems at all running OS X back to 10.5.

You do, however, need lots of memory. Virtual machines need the guest OS recommended memory *in addition* to the host OS recommended memory. Since Yosemite likes 4GB bare minimum, you won't be happy running two of them on a 4GB machine.

I have 24GB of memory, and right now I have 6 different versions of Mac OS running side-by-side. It does slow down noticeably when I try to update or reboot multiple guest operating systems, but that's more a function of them all being on the same external disk drive than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Fusion 7 supports OS X Yosemite and OS X Yosemite Server - 
https://www.vmware.com/au/support/fusion/faq/requirements#supported_guest